# handle error pages using PHP and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling

I want put some codes like below in my htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500
...
```

and have a PHP file which handles the error pages for me using GET ( file.php?a=404 ).

Now, I only need a htaccess code to rewrite the "/error/404" to "file.php?a=404" for me. What should I do ?!

Answer (score 1):

There's several other error documents that you might wish to customise.
400 - Bad request
401 - Authorization Required
403 - Forbidden directory
404 - Page not found
500 - Internal Server Error

For each one you want to use, simply add a line to your .htaccess file and create the corresponding page.

```
ErrorDocument 400 /errors/badrequest.html
ErrorDocument 401 /errors/authreqd.html
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/forbid.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
ErrorDocument 500 /errors/serverr.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/file.php?a=404
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/yourfile.php
```